# How to activate Authentication type - individual user accounts for Web API in .NET Core when we creating new Web APi service

Tags: .net, authentication, asp.net-core, .net-core

[image]
Why is it not possible to create a Web API project with Individual User Accounts Authorization type?

Answer (score 0):

See the following:
[Building Secure Web APIs with ASP.NET Core](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/dotnetConf/2016/Building-Secure-Web-APIs-with-ASPNET-Core#c636015653206312859)

In the last comment, [Dan Roth](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Speakers/daniel-roth) states that support for Individual Accounts in the Web API template for ASP.NET Core is not yet available.